NextJs - multiple components with async fetch - using params causes entire reload
I have multiple components within my page and each time I trigger a button to append a url param, it re-renders the entire page and fetches.
When I click on a button (client side), I want only that specific section to fetch the new data.
Right now, when I click on any button, it does append the url param but it fetches all the other components data as well
I tried using suspense without any luck. I assume I might have to look into parallel routes or use client side fetching

You can restructure the code to achieve this.

Isolate the APIs into their specific child components where the data is used.
Memoize the child components, so they don't rerender in case the parent rerenders.
And for re-routing or "appending to URLs" in your case, make sure you do shallow routing in next.js to stop the components from re-rendering.
(Check this link for more info on shallow routing in NextJS)

